# How do you refresh a view each time a user switches to a tab in a ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I have the following `FragmentStateAdapter`:

```
class TabPagerAdapter(activity: AppCompatActivity, private val itemsCount: Int) : FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemsCount
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        val default = CreateFragment()
        return when (position) {
            0 -> default
            1 -> {
                ProjectFragment()
            }
            else -> default
        }
    }
}
```

How could I refresh a specific fragment (I only need this for `ProjectFragment`) each time a user swipes to this tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider overriding onResume() method for ProjectFragment. Setting fields to null in onResume() might help.